# sum of corresponding elements of array including nil

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum

How can I sum in Ruby

```
[1, 2, nil, 4]
```

with

```
[nil, 2, nil, 4]
```

and have

```
[1, 4, nil, 8]
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example as follows:

```
 a = [1, 2, nil, 4]
 b = [nil, 2, nil, 4]
 a.map.with_index {|v,i| (v || b[i]) && v.to_i + b[i].to_i }
```

More estetic way is:

```
 a.zip(b).map {|v| v.compact.reduce(:+) }
```

**Explanation**: Here `#zip` just reconstructs the array with other passed value-by-value, so in 1st row will consist of 1st elements of each array, 2nd of 2nds, etc. Then `#compact`, and `#reduce` is applied of each of rows 1st, 2nd, etc. `#compact` just removes `nil` value, so they do not included in result. `#reduce` then construct a sum for each row, via `:+` operator between sum (by default it is `nil`), and value, so in output it resulted in the sum of values, of `nil` in case empty row.

If we'll get the more general approach, let's sum rows of the matrix.

```
 m = [ [  1, 2, nil, 4],
       [nil, 2, nil, 4] ]

 m.shift.zip(*m).map {|v| v.compact.reduce(:+) }
```

Comment: compact - reduce, is brilliant. +1

Comment: @CarySwoveland  and -1 + 1 too? =)

Comment: @CarySwoveland but with my first name , are you ok? =)

Comment: @CarySwoveland, the closest latin pronunciation is my name is: Malo Skrylevo

Comment: @JavierGiovannini some fixed to post =)

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanx, I have simplified one =)

Comment: Good! You are now free to go. (Ah! I was pronouncing it 'Skyrlevo'.)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ If you don't mind, could you explain how a.zip(b).map {|v| v.compact.reduce(:+) } does?

Answer (score 1):

```
a.zip(b).map {|x, y| x.nil? ? (y.nil? ? nil : y) : (y.nil? ? x : x + y)}
# => [1, 4, nil, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that makes use of the fact that `nil.to_i => O`:

```
a.zip(b).map { |e,f| [e,f]==[nil,nil] ? nil : e.to_i + f.to_i }
```